# People Picker Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to perform client side validation on people picker where in if the people picker is empty just to show an alert saying it is required. I am aware of java script and j query so if you guys can just drop in an example that would be great.

Thank You,

Comment: to set focus on the people Picker control : $("input[title='field name']").focus();

Comment: it does not work. i have tried this!

Comment: It works with  me

Comment: i shall try this again then. i am not able to set focus on text area. do you have a solution for that?

Comment: U can try the same with that too

Comment: i shall give it a try then!

Comment: the focus did not work for people picker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the SharePoint JavaScript file *clientpeoplepicker.js* is loaded before doing this validation.

Either by adding it as a reference or by loading it before doing the validation.

```
    var peoplePickerName = "Displayname for your people picker column"; 

    clientPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[$('[title="' + peoplePickerName + '"]')[0].id];

    if (clientPeoplePicker.TotalUserCount <= 0) {
//Reversing the condtion for the error. i.e user count less than or equal zero 
        alert("Cannot be empty"); 
    }
```

**Update**

To validate the people picker when trying to save the form and show the out of the box error message, we can do it like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    peoplePickerName = "PeoplePickerDisplayName"; 

    clientPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[$('[title="' + peoplePickerName + '"]')[0].id];

});
function PreSaveAction() {

    if (clientPeoplePicker.IsEmpty()) {
        clientPeoplePicker.AutoFillEnabled = true
        clientPeoplePicker.AllowEmpty = false
        clientPeoplePicker.HasInputError = true
        clientPeoplePicker.Validate()
        $("input.sp-peoplepicker-editorInput[id^='"+ peoplePickerName +"']").focus();

      return false;
   }
   else {
    return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i tried this method but it is not working. Do i need to include some files for this to work? I have a jquery min file already included. Do i need another file for it to work ?

Comment: Apologies, updated my answer.

Comment: actually i just put in == rather than > and it worked. I also want to know how to bring focus on the people picker field after the alert. Can that be done?

Comment: Did you work it out? Spent 2 hours going trough how SharePoint validates the control and sets the focus..

Comment: yes actually i am able to check the condition for the people picker just change the < sign to == and it checks the people picker. i am still not able to get the focus on people picker.

Comment: @jayantkhushalani See my update!

Comment: will surely try this out. let us see if the focus thing works or not !

Comment: the focus method did not work my friend.